# Automate removing users from group if not in OU

Tags: powershell

Earlier today, I got help adding members to a group if they are not a member of it.

```
$group = 'CN=Group1,OU=SomeOU,DC=domain,DC=local'
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(!memberof=$group)" -SearchBase "DC=domain,DC=local" |
Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf $group
```

Now I want to reverse that and remove members from the group if they are not in the specific OU I used as the -SearchBase. Does this look correct?

```
$group = 'CN=Group1,OU=SomeOU,DC=domain,DC=local'

Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group |
Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*DC=domain,DC=local" } |
Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf $group
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reverse the order would mean to query the Group's `Member` attribute and filter those DistinguishedNames not containing the base DistinguishedName. [`-notlike`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#matching-operators) can act as a filter on collection of values hence:

```bash
$group = 'CN=Group1,OU=SomeOU,DC=domain,DC=local'
$base  = 'DC=domain,DC=local'
(Get-ADGroup $group -Properties member).member -notlike "*$base" |
    Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf $group
```

Comment: Thanks for the lesson. I was slowly getting there as I edited my comment above. Going to disect what you have coded here.

Comment: @a3kop the code you have in your question now seems okeish (not sure if it will work as is, it for sure needs a wildcard `*` in the base OU like in my code), I'm also not sure if you can pipe the objects from `Get-ADGroupMember` to `Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` but the logic you have right there is fine too

Comment: How do you decide between Get-ADGroup and Get-ADGroupMember?

Comment: @a3kop `Get-ADGroup` querying the `MemberOf` attribute is much faster and you only need the DistinguishedName of the members. `Get-ADGroupMember` is slower because it get's you more information about the members which in this case you don't really need

Comment: In addition to the correct observations above, `Get-ADGroupMember` bombs out if the group size is too large. `(Get-Adgroup).memberof` doesn't have that limit (that I've encountered, assuming enough system memory).

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, if I run the query before the Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership, I should expect results, correct? Right now, I am getting nothing.

Comment: No @a3kop `Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` does not produce any output. If you receive output it would be an error

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/remove-adprincipalgroupmembership?view=windowsserver2022-ps#outputs